# AWS Amplify won't deploy because of CustomAuthTriggerResource error in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

When I created a pre-signup hook for Amplify, the following CloudFormation template was generated and it worked:

```
{
  "Description": "Custom Resource stack for Auth Trigger created using Amplify CLI",
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "env": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "userpoolId": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "userpoolArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "functionmyappwebappPreSignupName": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "functionmyappwebappPreSignupArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "functionmyappwebappPreSignupLambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "ShouldNotCreateEnvResources": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "env"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "UserPoolPreSignUpLambdaInvokePermission": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Ref": "functionmyappwebappPreSignupName"
        },
        "Principal": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": {
          "Ref": "userpoolArn"
        }
      }
    },
    "authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "authTriggerFnServiceRoleDefaultPolicyEC9285A8": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:UpdateUserPool"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": {
                "Ref": "userpoolArn"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "PolicyName": "authTriggerFnServiceRoleDefaultPolicyEC9285A8",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "authTriggerFn7FCFA449": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "ZipFile": "const response = require('cfn-response');\nconst aws = require('aws-sdk');\n\nexports.handler = async function (event, context) {\n  const physicalResourceId =\n    event.RequestType === 'Update' ? event.PhysicalResourceId : `${event.LogicalResourceId}-${event.ResourceProperties.userpoolId}`;\n\n  try {\n    const userPoolId = event.ResourceProperties.userpoolId;\n    const { lambdaConfig } = event.ResourceProperties;\n    const config = {};\n    const cognitoClient = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();\n    const userPoolConfig = await cognitoClient.describeUserPool({ UserPoolId: userPoolId }).promise();\n    const userPoolParams = userPoolConfig.UserPool;\n    // update userPool params\n\n    const updateUserPoolConfig = {\n      UserPoolId: userPoolParams.Id,\n      Policies: userPoolParams.Policies,\n      SmsVerificationMessage: userPoolParams.SmsVerificationMessage,\n      AccountRecoverySetting: userPoolParams.AccountRecoverySetting,\n      AdminCreateUserConfig: userPoolParams.AdminCreateUserConfig,\n      AutoVerifiedAttributes: userPoolParams.AutoVerifiedAttributes,\n      EmailConfiguration: userPoolParams.EmailConfiguration,\n      EmailVerificationMessage: userPoolParams.EmailVerificationMessage,\n      EmailVerificationSubject: userPoolParams.EmailVerificationSubject,\n      VerificationMessageTemplate: userPoolParams.VerificationMessageTemplate,\n      SmsAuthenticationMessage: userPoolParams.SmsAuthenticationMessage,\n      MfaConfiguration: userPoolParams.MfaConfiguration,\n      DeviceConfiguration: userPoolParams.DeviceConfiguration,\n      SmsConfiguration: userPoolParams.SmsConfiguration,\n      UserPoolTags: userPoolParams.UserPoolTags,\n      UserPoolAddOns: userPoolParams.UserPoolAddOns,\n    };\n\n    // removing undefined keys\n    Object.keys(updateUserPoolConfig).forEach((key) => updateUserPoolConfig[key] === undefined && delete updateUserPoolConfig[key]);\n\n    /* removing UnusedAccountValidityDays as deprecated\n    InvalidParameterException: Please use TemporaryPasswordValidityDays in PasswordPolicy instead of UnusedAccountValidityDays\n    */\n    if (updateUserPoolConfig.AdminCreateUserConfig && updateUserPoolConfig.AdminCreateUserConfig.UnusedAccountValidityDays) {\n      delete updateUserPoolConfig.AdminCreateUserConfig.UnusedAccountValidityDays;\n    }\n    lambdaConfig.forEach((lambda) => (config[`${lambda.triggerType}`] = lambda.lambdaFunctionArn));\n    if (event.RequestType === 'Delete') {\n      try {\n        updateUserPoolConfig.LambdaConfig = {};\n        console.log(`${event.RequestType}:`, JSON.stringify(updateUserPoolConfig));\n        const result = await cognitoClient.updateUserPool(updateUserPoolConfig).promise();\n        console.log(`delete response data ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);\n        await response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {}, physicalResourceId);\n      } catch (err) {\n        console.log(err.stack);\n        await response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, { err }, physicalResourceId);\n      }\n    }\n    if (event.RequestType === 'Update' || event.RequestType === 'Create') {\n      updateUserPoolConfig.LambdaConfig = config;\n      try {\n        const result = await cognitoClient.updateUserPool(updateUserPoolConfig).promise();\n        console.log(`createOrUpdate response data ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);\n        await response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {}, physicalResourceId);\n      } catch (err) {\n        console.log(err.stack);\n        await response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, { err }, physicalResourceId);\n      }\n    }\n  } catch (err) {\n    console.log(err.stack);\n    await response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, { err }, physicalResourceId);\n  }\n};\n"
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "Runtime": "nodejs14.x"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "authTriggerFnServiceRoleDefaultPolicyEC9285A8",
        "authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67"
      ]
    },
    "CustomAuthTriggerResource": {
      "Type": "Custom::CustomAuthTriggerResourceOutputs",
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "authTriggerFn7FCFA449",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "userpoolId": {
          "Ref": "userpoolId"
        },
        "lambdaConfig": [
          {
            "triggerType": "PreSignUp",
            "lambdaFunctionName": "myappwebappPreSignup",
            "lambdaFunctionArn": {
              "Ref": "functionmyappwebappPreSignupArn"
            }
          }
        ],
        "nonce": "cd55fb39-4ef8-416e-bc0b-178353ecc845"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "authTriggerFn7FCFA449",
        "authTriggerFnServiceRoleDefaultPolicyEC9285A8",
        "authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67"
      ],
      "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Delete",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete"
    }
  }
}
```

After some changes, I think I accidentally deleted `authTriggerFn7FCFA449` and the whole deployment stopped working. CloudFormation started complaining like this:

```
Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:510148651032:function:amplify-amplify65170398e4384-authTriggerFn7FCFA449-wBSraCi16QuH
(Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 7195cef0-164c-4095-9de3-8a8309086a99; Proxy: null)
```

After detecting the drift I managed to recreate the Lambda, with all the roles, tags, code, cfn-response properly set up. Now, there's no drift. Additionally, the previous error dissapears.

However, CloudFormation waits for an hour and then is stuck at **UPDATE_FAILED** on `CustomAuthTriggerResource` with the following problem:

```
CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource.
Please check your logs for requestId [44595a05-67c1-4594-b16b-096ce6506d96].
If you are using the Python cfn-response module, you may need to update your Lambda function code so that CloudFormation can attach the updated version.
```

All other resources (`authTriggerFn7FCFA449`, `authTriggerFnServiceRole08093B67`, `authTriggerFnServiceRoleDefaultPolicyEC9285A8`, `UserPoolPreSignUpLambdaInvokePermission`) are at **CREATE_COMPLETE** and **UPDATE_COMPLETE**.

Looking at the `amplify-amplify65170398e4384-authTriggerFn7FCFA449-wBSraCi16QuH` logs, there is no such request. How do I proceed from here?

No git pushes, amplify pushes or stack updates fix the situation.

---

Edit: I think this is related: [GitHub: Make the CustomAuthTriggerResource timeout configurable #9837](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9837)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a known problem. Solved using [GitHub Issue: Make the CustomAuthTriggerResource timeout configurable](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9837) and the [AWS documentation on stuck resources](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-lambda-resource-delete)

#### Workaround

1. Add one line showing the CloudFormation event at the beginning of the current Lambda function ...authTriggerFn7FCFA449 via Lambda console. For example, `console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));`
2. Click the "continue update rollback" button on CloudFormation console as the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-continueupdaterollback.html) shows
3. Watch the CloudWatch log stream of the above Lambda function, note the S3 pre-signed URL, PhysicalResourceId, StackId, LogicalResourceId. An output will look like

```
{
    "RequestType": "Update",
    "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:1234567:function:amplify-test9656353151-dev-1-authTriggerFn7FCFA449-xyz",
    "ResponseURL": "https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-apsoutheast2.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aap-sou...00d761385cd62013820dc780bc07d07e021f77",
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:1234567:stack/amplify-test9656353151-dev-165513-AuthTriggerCustomLambdaStack-VZC2CVEFA8GA/00876ee0-93a7-11ec-b1d1-xyz",
    "RequestId": "82bf2ca0-061e-4895-ad70-xyz",
    "LogicalResourceId": "CustomAuthTriggerResource",
    "PhysicalResourceId": "2022/02/22/[$LATEST]f72b84eb...54d7ef4",
    "ResourceType": "Custom::CustomAuthTriggerResourceOutputs",
    ...
}
```

4. According to this [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-lambda-resource-delete/) , manually construct a cURL SUCCESS request based on the observed information. Note that the cURL destination URL should be the the "ResponseURL" above. Since it is a custom resource, you cannot use [CloudFormation CLI signal-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/signal-resource.html) to unblock it. The cURL request looks like:

```
$ curl -H 'Content-Type: ''' -X PUT -d '{"Status": "SUCCESS","PhysicalResourceId": "2022/02/22/[$LATEST]f72b84eb...54d7ef4","StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:1234567:stack/amplify-test9656353151-dev-165513-AuthTriggerCustomLambdaStack-VZC2CVEFA8GA/00876ee0-93a7-11ec-b1d1-xyz","RequestId": "82bf2ca0-061e-4895-ad70-xyz","LogicalResourceId": "CustomAuthTriggerResource"}' 'https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-apsoutheast2.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aap-sou...00d761385cd62013820dc780bc07d07e021f77'
```

5. Once you send the SUCCESS request out, CloudFormation stack will restore to UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state, and user can make further push.

Then adjust the lambda timeout in both the Lambda and the CF managing the lambda to 300 seconds.